# How to group mutliple modules into a single namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a python3.5 project which I decided to make a one class per module. I decided to do so because i found out my files were very long and I it was hard to me to understand whats going on.

After I made the change I feel like I am repeating myself in each import file:

```
from school.student import Student
from school.classroom import ClassRoom
from school.teacher import Teacher
```

Is there any way pass that repeat? I would like that my imports will be more like:

```
from school import Student, ClassRoom, Teacher
```

Comment: "which I decided to make a one class per module" - why? This isn't Java; you don't need to do that.

Comment: Why one class per module in this case? Aren't all these models of the same domain? Maybe they belong together?

Comment: He said he did it for readability, which is a very reasonable motivation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `__init__` module to accomplish this. The contents of an `__init__` module are evaluated when the parent module/package is imported. Like this:

```
# __init__.py
from school.student import Student
from school.classroom import ClassRoom
from school.teacher import Teacher
```

This brings `Student`, `ClassRoom` and `Teacher` into the `school` namespace. Now you can import using the `school` module as you like.

Caution: it is really easy to pollute your namespace this way. It's probably better to import explicitly in each module the way you started, or to use the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36556726/2437514) and use your classes employing explicit module references (e.g., `school.Teacher()` instead of `Teacher()`).

If you feel `school.Teacher()` is too long, you can shorten things up a bit this way:

```
import school as sch
teacher = sch.Teacher()
```

etc etc.

However, on the other hand, if those classes are objects that *should* be available at the package level, importing them into the package namespace is probably the correct thing to do. Only you can make that determination.

Answer (score 7):

I supposed `school` is a package, if not you need to create a package and put all your modules into the package then create a `__init__.py` file where you basically glue everything together. You need to use a relative import in your `__init__.py` file.

You package must now look like this:

```
school/
__init__.py
student.py
classroom.py
teacher.py
```

Then you `__init__.py` must look like this:

```
from .student import Students
from .classroom import ClassRoom
from .teacher import Teacher
```

Next only call your class using package name like this:

```
import school
t = school.Teacher()
```

Comment: I think as the accepted answer shows it isn't true that the relative imports are needed (the from .student style) so 'must look like' is strong. There is consensus that they are needed or better, so the style in the accepted answer may be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Just put all the classes in module `school.py`. That's what **Python** modules are for. What you just showed us is the **Java** way(probably) of maintaining namespace through packages. If you still want to go that way then just make a moule `all.py` and write,

```
# all.py
from school.student import Student
from school.classroom import ClassRoom
from school.teacher import Teacher
```

and in you main file, write `from school.all import Student, ClassRoom, Teacher`
But you can see that's redundant and ugly.