# Python module grouping

Tags: python, module

Is there a way in python to declare all the modules I want in one place? For example:

**Modules.py**

```
import math
import os
import re
...
```

**main.py**

```
import modules

os.path(path)
re.search(test)
```

Will help with organization and redundant code.

Comment: `from modules import *`. Will not help in organization and will not suppress redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file called `modules.py`.

In modules.py:

```
import a
import b
import c
...
```

As long as `modules.py` and the script you are running are in the same dir, you can use `from modules import *` and it will be imported!

Comment: I should have clarified this but I'm not sure if this would happen but, will I need to type `modules.a`?

Comment: This would not work as you are describing, you would need `modules.a` etc, and also, it is not a circular import (which is generally a *bad* thing)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: For a quick fix, you can list the modules on the same line.

```
import math, os, re

os.path(path)
```

Option 2: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556418/how-to-group-mutliple-modules-into-a-single-namespace) for using a namespace to group modules.